# Exibir dados agrupados

Tags: mysql, sql

estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados e estou tendo dificuldades com duplicações de dados, até agora, essa é minha query:

```
SELECT * FROM tec_postagens tp
INNER JOIN tec_historico_status th ON tp.protocolo=th.protocolo
WHERE tp.protocolo = '1168'
ORDER BY tp.protocolo DESC, tp.datahora DESC
```

o resultado é :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a primeira tabela é `tec_postagens`, a segunda é `tec_historico_status`, preciso mostrar todas as postagens junto com os dados da `tec_historico_status` ambas tem o mesmo `protocolo` o que diferencia é a `datahora` preciso mostrar por ordem da `datahora`

obrigado.

Comment: Ao meu ver não está errado. Pois você esta vinculando tudo numa query só. Essas duplicidades deve ser ajustadas utilizando a linguagem de programação na sua aplicação.

Comment: Você apenas não quer que apareça os dados duplicados? Não da pra usar o DISTINCT?

Comment: nunca usei DISTINCT @ReneSá , poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Assim: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tec_postagens tp
INNER JOIN tec_historico_status th ON tp.protocolo=th.protocolo
WHERE tp.protocolo = '1168'
ORDER BY tp.protocolo DESC, tp.datahora DESC`

Com o DISTINCT, se houver vários resultados idênticos, avaliando a sequencia pelo ORDER BY, ele retorna somente um. @Rene, posta a solução como resposta.

Comment: ficou o mesmo resultado @GustavoCinque

Comment: Furlan onde há repetição, não estou a perceber...

Comment: na coluna postagem @JorgeB.

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o seu problema na pergunta. Não dá para perceber o que você quer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se não quer repetição na coluna `postagem` tem de fazer um `GROUP BY` dessa coluna:

```
SELECT * FROM tec_postagens tp
INNER JOIN tec_historico_status th ON tp.protocolo=th.protocolo
WHERE tp.protocolo = '1168'
ORDER BY tp.protocolo DESC, tp.datahora DESC
GROUP BY tp.postagem
```

[EDIT]

Se é só para ordenar pela `datahora` da segunda tabela é só trocar

```
ORDER BY tp.protocolo DESC, tp.datahora DESC
```

por

```
ORDER BY tp.protocolo DESC, th.datahora DESC
```

**Repare que mudei `tp.datahora` por `th.datahora`**

Comment: certo @Jorge mas agora eu perco algumas 'alteracoes' ele perde por causa do GROUP

Comment: @Furlan Qual das linhas dali da imagem queres que NÃO apareça?

Comment: as postagens repetidas não podem aparecer, e nao pode perder as alterações

Comment: Tiravas alguma linha inteira dali? Diz-me o numero da linha que queres que não apareça daquela tabela da imagem

Comment: nao tem que tirar nada, quero mostrar apenas as postagens e as alterações de acordo com a hora de cada uma, ou seja, listando elas ordenada pela coluna 'datahora'

Comment: Vê a minha edição... é isso?

Comment: valew galera pela ajuda, consegui resolver meu erro, eu mudei minha estrutura, obrigado a todos, valew @Jorge

Comment: @JorgeB. Ótimo exemplo +1

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa maneira, usando `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tec_postagens tp 
INNER JOIN tec_historico_status th ON tp.protocolo=th.protocolo 
WHERE tp.protocolo = '1168' 
ORDER BY tp.protocolo DESC, tp.datahora DESC
```

Se assim não funcionar, tente trocar o `*` pelos nomes das colunas.

Comment: ta exibindo, so que tipo, a coluna postagem ta repetindo os valores, eu precisava exibir as postagem e as alterações de acordo com o horario, postagem 2014-11-11 10:00:00, alteracao 2014-11-11 11:00:00 e assim por diante entendeu

Comment: Entendi, mas como elas são exibidas? porque na query voce pede para serem exibidas de modo decrescente